# Matplotlib does not recognize custom font install as having a bold weight

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed a font in matplotlib in `~/.local/share/fonts. matplotlib has no trouble finding the font:

```
import os
fp=matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=os.getenv('HOME')+'/.local/share/fonts/arial-Bold.ttf')
fp.__dict__
```

outputs

```
{'_family': ['sans-serif'],
 '_slant': 'normal',
 '_variant': 'normal',
 '_weight': 'normal',
 '_stretch': 'normal',
 '_file': '<home>/.local/share/fonts/arial-Bold.ttf',
 '_size': 12.0,
 '_math_fontfamily': 'dejavusans'}
```

The issue is that it is not being recognized as encoding the "bold" weight of the "arial" family. How do I set this up so that different slants/variants/weights etc are organized properly after install?